# Private repo composer.json not being used

Tags: php, git, composer-php

My problem is that a privately made repo's composer.json seems to be broken when trying to use it as a package elsewhere.

I have a private repo with code needed for other projects. The repo's composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "somevendor/global",

    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.21"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "" : "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "somedir/somefile.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

The `src` is in the base directory of the repo, and contains PSR-4 namespaced classes. I have namespace folders within that, e.g. a `Foo` directory with classes in the `Foo` namespace:

```
-- src
      -- Foo
         // some Foo\... classes
   // some global namespace classes
-- somedir
   somefile.php // A file with helper functions
```

In the project folder, I'm accessing the `somevendor/global` repo via a composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "somevendor/global-folder": "dev-master"
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "somevendor/global",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "type": "package",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@bitbucket.org/somevendor/global.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Running `composer install` in the project folder seems to work at first. I have installed SSH keys properly so it can access the private repo on Bitbucket and grab the files:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing somevendor/global (dev-master master)
    Cloning master

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

And then in the project's PHP code I `require vendor/autoload.php`, but none of the classes are being autoloaded, including the `Carbon` package specified in the first repo's composer.json file:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo\Foo' not found in...`

I've clearly made a mistake here, have I structured the first repo wrongly?

Comment: You should specify a namespace in your composer.json's psr-4 autoload i.e. `"Carbon": "src/"`

Comment: I thought composer just took care of the other public dependencies?

Comment: No! Composer also defines the scope of local packages and how they should be handled when *used* as a dependency

Comment: So in the global composer.json I need to add autoload entries for every dependency it has? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, the dependency defines its own auto loading rules. You just haven't defined any by the look of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" this by taking out all of the "require" entries from the remote repo's `composer.json` file and moving them to the local website's `composer.json` file.

This is what the files looked like:

The remote private repo's `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "somevendor/global",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "" : "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "functions/functions.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

The local website's `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.21",
        "somevendor/global": "dev-master"
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:somevendor/global.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

It kept throwing `Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException` because I forgot to put the `name` into the remote repo's `composer.json` file, so don't forget that bit!

Also remember to set up your git ssh keys if you've set them up. I used [this Bitbucket tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) to do this.